# Make facebook like box adjust to image size

Tags: html, css

Here's a fiddle with my current code, for context:  http://jsfiddle.net/GgvLQ/

I have a client who wants a set of Facebook links to always stay aligned with the bottom of an image that is to the left of the links, no matter what size the image is.  I tried wrapping everything but the image in a div, setting the min-height to the smallest possible image the client will use, and positioning the links absolute to the bottom of the wrapper (positioned relatively), but then the image just overlaps the links when the size is large.  I'm not really sure what to do at this point.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I positioned the like buttons right under your image.  Then depending on image size, you `position: absolute;` then make adjustments.

Not sure how many you have to do, but here ya:  http://jsfiddle.net/stillb4llin/GgvLQ/1/

If you aren't looking for this, let me know.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that if you increase the size of the image, which my client will inevitably do, it will overlap the facebook links.  It has to be responsive to the changing size of the image, because it's a piece of code that is reused for multiple campaigns. 

I don't even know if what I want to do is possible, at this point, without investing way more time than what my client ought to for what seems like a fairly unnecessary design change.

Comment: Can you show me how you want the fb links?
http://i.imgur.com/jW3I5.png


I think I have the concept for how you want the buttons:
http://jsfiddle.net/stillb4llin/zFa99/10/


I'm pretty sure if we can get it to all work with the text inside a div... we can make it happen.


I apologize if my links don't work.


edit 1,2,3,4: hit enter too many times
edit 4: fixed links

Comment: ran out of editing time.  sorry about readability.  I don't know how to format and I tried over and over

Comment: It would look like how it looks in the top right example, and would be pushed with the text to the right as the image got bigger.  I'm not sure if the concept worked, because if I make the image pixel size and then increase it to 400px or so, it still overlaps the facebook links.

Comment: I'm going to think about this some more.  I wish it had some more upvotes!